# sudo pip installでsudo: pip: command not foundのエラー

Tags: python

Pygameをinstallしようとしているのですが、

```
$sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
sudo: pip: command not found
```

となってしまいます。

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

も実行しておりますが、同じエラーになっていまします。
どうすればいいのでしょうか。

Python:2.7
OS:OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy_install ではなく https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ にある [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) を取得・保存して、このファイルを以下のように実行して下さい。

```
python get-pip.py
```

なお、（easy_installを使っても同じですが）pipはこのとき使っているpythonの環境にインストールされます。Macには複数のPythonがはじめからインストールされているため、上記のget-pip.pyを実行する時点で、どのPythonの環境にインストールしたいのかを意識して、使用するpythonインタプリタを選択して下さい。

上記でインストールして、それでもpipが実行出来ない場合は、python get-pip.py を実行した際のコンソールログを質問に追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

`pip`自体のインストールがされていない（または適切にセットアップされていない）ようなので、[`get-pip.py`を使ってのインストール](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#install-pip)からやり直してみた方がいいと思います。

*参考：`pip`がデフォルトで Python に含まれているのは、2.7.9以降*